# Mac Terminal Color Changes after ssh

Tags: macos, mac, terminal.app

Whenever I ssh to my linux system from Mac. 
It started using remote system color. 
Is there a way I can force it to use original color ?

Comment: Can't you just change which terminal that session uses? I think it defaults to 'xterm-color', or 'xterm-color256'? I wanted to disable colors, so I believe I just set that session to use 'xterm'. But, maybe this is not what you're referring to...

Comment: but those color don't match with my mac terminal theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not easily. It no longer knows what the original system's colors are after you ssh, so you'd have to configure the local ssh to send that information as environment variables, and the remote ssh to read them. See `SendEnv` in the `ssh_config(5)` man page, `AcceptEnv` in the `sshd_config(5)` man page, and the **SSHRC** section of the `sshd(8)` man page.